# Value attribute not working for Radio Button Angular

Tags: html, angular, radio-button

I am trying to create a dynamic form that includes the Radio Buttons.

```
<div *ngFor="let opt of question.options">
         <input [formControlName]="question.key" [value]="opt.key" [type]="question.controlType" [id]="opt.key" [name]="question.key"/>
         <label [htmlFor]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</label>
</div>
```

But the value attribute is empty in the HTML when the Page is loaded. What could the possible reason ?

```
<input _ngcontent-mjy-c129="" ng-reflect-name="gender" type="radio" value="" id="male" name="gender" class="ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-touched">
```

Comment: Update the question JSON value here

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved after removing the FormControl from the input elements. I think the initial value of form control was overriding the new values which I was trying to set.

Answer (score 0):

**Be sure you call data before initializing the form**